# Install MySQL Client in Django Show Error

Tags: python, mysql, django

Hi I am trying to install `Mysqlclient` in Django and I got this message

```
collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\usermo~1\virtua~1\tmsv2_~2\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\userMO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vzfx29bg\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\userMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-rd_6y67h' --python-tag cp37:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-Ic:\users\user moe\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\users\user moe\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
  _mysql.c
  MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command 'c:\users\usermo~1\virtua~1\tmsv2_~2\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\userMO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vzfx29bg\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\userMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ea_7lykd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\usermo~1\virtua~1\tmsv2_~2\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient':
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 "-IC:\Program Files
(x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" "-Ic:\users\user moe\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-Ic:\users\user moe\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.7\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "'c:\users\usermo~1\virtua~1\tmsv2_~2\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\userMO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vzfx29bg\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\userMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ea_7lykd\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\usermo~1\virtua~1\tmsv2_~2\include\site\python3.7\mysqlclient'" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\userMO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vzfx29bg\mysqlclient\
```

I already tried several way

- `pip install opencv-contrib-python` (can install no work)
- `pip install mysqlclient==1.3.12` (show same error)
- I install the mycsqlclient from [Wheel Link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) (show this error  `mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`)

My python version is: 3.7.3

(I come from desktop environment and while I read the Django, its say "Ridiculously fast" but now for MySQL connection problem took 4 days already).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have downloaded the wrong wheel. The error message says you tried to install `mysqlclient-1.4.2-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl`, which is for Python 3.8.

Since you are using Python 3.7, you should use either `mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win32.whl` or `mysqlclient‑1.4.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl` depending on whether you have installed 32-bit or 64-bit Python.

Comment: Thanks, btw amd64 are for 64-bit window, right? I fixed this issue by installing with normal wheel (not 64 bit) on a 64-bit window.

Comment: Amd64 is for 64-bit Python. You can install 32-bit Python on 64-bit Windows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your Build Tools cannot handle some `.h` files. You can use [unofficial precompiled package database](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) to get already compiled `mysqlclient`. 
After downloading it run

```
pip install name-of-whl-file.whl
```

If the python+win version of whl file fails to install, try using another version. Always works for me if Build Tools fail.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pymysql

1.Install pymysql

```
pip install pymysql
```

2. Modify your **init**.py file

   `import pymysql`

   `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()`

You can start your project

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I try to install mysqlclient in windows. after much time spent in this error. I found a result in the result install the latest visual studio and visual studio build tools. if programmer and only work on coding then transfer windows to ubuntu.i transfer on Ubuntu and enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pip install mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

if it did'nt work, then use the 32bit version

```
 pip install mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp38-cp38-win32.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to install mysql-client is to go to [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient) and you will find many mysql-client wheels.

- Download the first one #do not change the name of the file,,
- open command prompt,
- use cd to go to the directory where your wheel has been installed,
- then use pip install (name of file) #use .whl as well

if it doesn't work, download the second one and repeat the process, if that doesn't work as well, keep on downloading until I guarantee you that at least one of them would be installed in your computer